# meaning of the word "ever" before a verb in the continuous form in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the context:

> "Before ever **writing** Chapter one, he will write synopsis after synopsis, for up to a year, ironing out all the wrinkles, developing not just plot and peripeteia (or twists) but character." — Andy Martin, The Independent, 25 Nov. 2016

Did the author use the word *ever* for emphasis there? If not, then what is it for there? Wouldn't the sentence make more sense without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is an ever/never issue**.

Please check out **the transformations** one can make while keeping the same basic meanings.

- before ever doing something:
  **ever is indirectly related to never. Both are adverbs**

The second one can be contrasted with: never doing something

- **Before I ever do any work**, I try to have fun.
- **I never do any work before** I try to have fun.

"**Before ever writing Chapter One**, he will etc."
is the same as:

"**He will never write Chapter One before** he does [whatever]

That should help you understand ever, the adverb.

The adverb ever can be used like this regardless of tense.

- **Before ever studying at university**, he played professional soccer.
- **He never studied at university before** playing professional soccer.

The point my answer is making is *the transformation of*: Before ever + verbING or verb phrase **into** subject + verb + never + before +verbING.

**Before ever giving the dog a bath**, I clean the house.

**I never give the dog a bath** **before** I clean the house. [a general statement]

It's easier to grasp using never/ever in the simple present as a general statement about something. That is basic usage that ELLers usually learn in a first-year English course, along with the other common adverbs of frequency: sometimes and always. Of course, there are many more as well.

**Ever and never** are related to each other:
- Do you ever go out after dark?
- No, I never go out after dark?

Comment: Could be rephrased like this? "He always  played professional soccer, before studying at university."

Comment: Sorry, but this use of "ever" is really hard to grasp

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope You are absolutely right about that. It's tricky. Please take another look at the patterns and try to make one up for yourself. In the soccer example, *never* is not exactly like the *never* in: I never drink coffee. A general statement. The *never* applies only to the *studying at the university*. See? No, it has nothing to do with **always**. Ever and never are like peas in a pod. [idiom].Do you ever play soccer? No, I never play soccer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the first chapter of a particular book but of *any* book he writes.

> Before he ever sits down to the first course, he will scout out the restaurant's kitchen.
>
> Before ever sitting down to the first course, he will scout out the restaurant's kitchen.

To paraphrase, **whenever** he visits a restaurant he scouts out the kitchen before sitting down to the first course.

**ever** there could be paraphrased "under any circumstances, at any time"

Comment: So whar does the word "ever" mean there?

Comment: @Dmytro O'Hope. Why do you think **ever** means something different than its usual meaning?  *He **will write** synopsis after synopsis* refers to his **customary practice**. So, **whenever** he writes a book, he spends time, up to a year, "ironing out all the wrinkles" beforehand.

Comment: Does it mean always there? It is actually difficult to get it

Comment: **ever** there could be paraphrased "under any  circumstances, at any time".

Comment: This is not an instance of emphatic **ever**: *The meal was ever so tasty*.

Comment: I am confused. Does it mean "always" or "as usual"?

Comment: Here is the dfenition of the phrase "at any time": If something could happen at any time, it is possible that it will happen very soon, though nobody can predict exactly when." It doesn't appear to fit

Comment: I do not understand your comment, and I don't understand the relevancy of prediction to the meaning here. I've told you what the sentence means. Or are you trying to tell me what it means?  *Before sitting down to write the first chapter of **any** book (at any time), it is his cusomtary practice to iron out the wrinkles first.*